# How to add conditional comments to hamlet templates?

Tags: haskell, yesod, conditional-comments, hamlet, html

How can I add [conditional comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) (or any kind of Html comment) to [Shakespearean templates](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates)?

If I add

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..." media="screen">
<![endif]-->
```

to my hamlet template just an empty line is generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scaffolded project have an example of conditional comments at **templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet**:

```
\<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```